# flow doesn't work properly on Windows (initialization is either too slow or doesn't finish at all)

Tags: node.js, typescript, meteor

I am working on a relatively big Meteor project. This project is using `flow --show-all-branches` for type checking.

I am on Windows, while most of my colleagues are on Mac OS. I managed to get most things working well (sometimes slow but tolerable). For example, the build takes around 15 minutes. But I can't get `flow` to work at all. Trying to launch it either via `meteor npm run ...` or `npm run ...`, in both cases it takes insanely long (spending several hours on `"Please wait. Server is initializing (parsed files..."`)), and even after that, doesn't always start. For my colleagues on Mac OS, it takes minutes or even seconds.

Are there some specifics about using `flow` on Windows, that I need to be aware of? Is there something I can put into `.flowconfig`? Or maybe, an alternative way to launch it that I could try?